# Change key bindings on buffer switch

Tags: key-bindings

I'm a new Emacs user so its possible that I've misunderstood something. **I'm looking for a function that automatically changes my current key bindings depending on the current major mode.**

My approach was the following:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-c r") 'mark-done-and-archive))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-c r") 'cider-restart))
```

Consider the following scenario:

1. Open a new org-file in emacs, `"C-c r"` is now bound to `mark-done-and-archive`.
2. Open a new clj-file in emacs, `"C-c r"`  is now bound to `cider-restart`.
3. Switch back to my org file using for example `ivy-switch-buffer` or `windmove-right`, `"C-c r"` is still bound to `cider-restart`, even though the current major mode is `org-mode`.

I'm looking for something that redefines the key bindings on every window/buffer switch to the ones I defined for that particular mode.

Comment: Mode hooks are run whenever you create a buffer with a certain mode or switch modes. You're setting a global keymap instead of the keymap for the mode you're in. I don't know how normal mode in evil works, so I don't know if commands starting with `C-c` are taken from the major mode keymap instead of the evil's major mode keymap.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [local keymaps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Keymaps.html). Every well-behaved Emacs major mode, as well as some minor modes, come with their own keymap. The key to your solution is modifying the mode's local keymap, not `evil-normal-state-map`, which is active globally. See the [FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Binding-keys-to-commands.html) for some examples.

Comment: This indeed did the trick, thank you both for clarifying this.

Comment: @Basil: Please consider posting your comment as an answer, so it can be accepted. Comments can be deleted anytime, and this good question has a good answer, which can help people.

Comment: Thanks @Drew, will write something up later. I often opt for a comment first because a) I don't always have the time for what I expect of an answer; b) it helps clarify what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Basil: Sounds good. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

- I am not an [`evil`](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil) user so my understanding of `evil-normal-state-map` may be inaccurate
- There exist naughty Emacs modes in the wild which do not follow all of the standard conventions described in this answer; such cases can be considered bugs and ought to be disciplined

---

> I'm looking for a function that automatically changes my current keybindings depending on the current major mode.

You're in luck! This is a fundamental design feature of Emacs modes<sup>[1]</sup> and their interplay with keymaps<sup>[2, 3]</sup>. The key to achieving your desired behaviour simply lies in knowing which keymap to customise<sup>[4]</sup> and when / how<sup>[5]</sup>.

In summary of the manual nodes linked in the footnotes, it is useful to note:

- Every buffer has a single `major-mode` and any number of minor modes enabled at a time
- All modes are (generally) independent of one another and of any other buffer's modes
- Enabling a major mode in a buffer automatically enables its associated keymap for that buffer<sup>[6]</sup>; this is also true of some, but not all, minor modes
- Enabling any mode runs its dedicated mode hook<sup>[7]</sup>

AIUI, `evil-normal-state-map` is the keymap of a global minor mode, meaning it can be (and usually is) active in multiple buffers, irrespective of their `major-mode`. Furthermore, though keymaps of both major and minor modes may not always be active, the variable that holds them (in this case `evil-normal-state-map`) is a global definition. This means that modifying `evil-normal-state-map` (from any buffer) will affect all buffers which have that minor mode enabled. This explains your reported behaviour when switching between buffers. See [`(elisp) Active Keymaps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Active-Keymaps.html) for a more detailed and technical explanation of this.

So, in order to bind the same key to different commands in `org-mode` and `clojure-mode` buffers, you should instead be customising the local (major mode) keymap in the corresponding mode hook:

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c r") #'mark-done-and-archive)))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key (kbd "C-c r") #'cider-restart)))
```

which is equivalent to

```el
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") #'mark-done-and-archive)))

(add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") #'cider-restart)))
```

This, however, will cause the same (redundant) operation to be performed every time one of these major modes is enabled. Since the two mode maps are global variables, a single modification after they are defined and before they are used for the first time will suffice:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'org
  (define-key org-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") #'mark-done-and-archive))

(with-eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
  (define-key clojure-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") #'cider-restart))
```

---

**Footnotes**

1. [`(emacs) Major Modes`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Major-Modes.html)
2. [`(eintr) Keymaps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Keymaps.html)
3. [`(elisp) Keymap Basics`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Keymap-Basics.html)
4. [`(emacs) Rebinding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rebinding.html)
5. [`(emacs) Init Rebinding`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html)
6. [`(emacs) Local Keymaps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Local-Keymaps.html)
7. [`(emacs) Hooks`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hooks.html)

Comment: Awesome answer. Just what a emacs-newbie needs!